# How to Have the item in the listview after clicked

Tags: android, listview

I'm new in Android, I have a `listview` of items, and I have created a popup menu, when the user press a row he must have an item in a other activity.
my problem is, he sends me always the first item... no matter where I click in the `listview`.

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(busqueda.this, productos,
                R.layout.list_layout, new String[]{"codigo", "descrip", "precio", "fisicolug"},
                new int[]{R.id.txtCodigo, R.id.txtDescrip, R.id.txtPrecio, R.id.Stock});
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(lista);
        registerForContextMenu(textView);
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    MenuInflater inflate = getMenuInflater();
    if (v.getId() == R.id.listView) {
        inflate.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }
}
public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.masIn:
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCodigo);
            String text = textView.getText().toString();
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Resultado.class);
            intent.putExtra("CODIGO", text);
            startActivity(intent);
            super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: You have to send positions of the the details page.
every row have their unique position.

Answer (score 0):

By using listview setOnItemClickListener() you can handle the click event of listview

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thx Swapnil i did it that way buy when i click on the popup menu , he did'nt send men nothing ,even open the other activity...

lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCodigo);

                    }
                });